# Elements added to inner html with JavaScript not persisting?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to populate a div with a certain character which repeats itself a number of times, a pretty basic task, or so I thought, for which I wrote the following JS method:

```
<script>
            function populateTarget()
                {
                    var target = document.getElementById("div_target");
                    var nrSteps = parseInt(document.getElementById("nr").value);

                    for (var i=0;i<nrSteps;i++)
                        {
                            target.innerHTML+=("x");
                        }
                }
</script>
```

The problem is that "x"'es appear but only for a fraction of a second which I can only notice while I have firebug on.

the function is triggered of a button in this form:

```
             <form>
                    Nr de caractere: <input type="text" value="1" id="nr"/>
                    <br/>
                    Caracterul dorit:
                    <select id="chr">
                      <option value="c">c</option>
                      <option value="b">b</option>
                      <option value="g">g</option>
                      <option value="o">o</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                    <button onclick="populateTarget()"> Genereaza</button>
                </form>
```

This is the div:

```
 <style >
    body
    {
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #div_target,#div_form
    {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        border:5px solid white;
    }

    #div_target
    {
        float: left;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
</style>

 <div id="div_target">
 </div>
```

No other functions mess with the inner html of the div after this, and while I know adding directly to the innerHTML is a very inelegant method I just wanted to check that I could add character before writing something more advanced.

A [codepen](http://cdpn.io/cfvrJ) of my code.

Does anybody have a idea on what I'm doing wrong, and maybe a solution preferably one in which I use only pure JS, no libraries?

Comment: What's `document.getElementById("nr")` and what calls `populateTarget();`?

Comment: Did you check nrSteps using the console ? There can be many reasons for it to be NaN, for example it's not an input, or it needs to be trimmed...

Comment: Something like `target.innerHTML+=("x");` is a real Javascript disaster. I get that you're a Javascript newbie, so my advice is to understand why that snippet is terrible as soon as possible.

Comment: Is there some other piece of javascript code that overwrites the innerHtml of `div_target` after `populateTarget()` is invoked? One general suggestion would be to generate the htmlText first and then append to `target.innerHtml` instead of updating it for each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps reloading the page when you fire the event that runs your `populateTarget` function?  Is it in a form with an action such as ".", triggered by a button, for instance?

That would explain the behavior you're seeing.

If the function ended with `return false;`, it might prevent this, if my guess is right.

Comment: I added a `return false` and while it didn't work I think your ideea of the page reloading has merit so I added the form.

Comment: Well, that was an idea to diagnose the problem, not as a solution.  Can you post a JSFiddle, JSBin, or Codepen demo?

Comment: Change the onclick to `onclick="populateTarget(); return false;"` and I think it will solve your problem.  You were reloading the page as suspected.

Comment: The problem indeed was that the form was reposting when I pushed the button, I solved the issue by taking the button out of the form. I'll fiddle with the function to make it more elegant.